# How to get accumulate value of openTSDB use bosun?

Tags: opentsdb, bosun

I have a counter, which named,for example "mysvr.method_name1" with 3 tagk/v.It's a counter type of openTSDB which means query times in my situation.How can I get the accumulate value of it in past 30 days(in my situation, total requests number in 30 days).
I use `q` method like below:

```
q("sum:mysvr.method_name1{tag1=v1}", "1590940800", "1593532800")
```

but it looks like the number series not monotone increasing due to server restart, missing tagk/v  or some other reasons.
So it's seam like the below query will not meet my requirement:

```
diff(q("sum:mysvr.method_name1{tag1=v1}", "1590940800", "1593532800"))
```

how shall I do to fetch the accumulate value for counter in the given time period?
The only thing I can make sure is the below is mean QPS in my situation:

```
avg(q("sum:rate{counter}:mysvr.method_name1{tag1=v1}", "1590940800", "1593532800"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(q("sum:rate{counter}:mysvr.method_name1{tag1=v1}", "1590940800", "1593532800"))
```

works for my situation,the gap is multiply by sample time duration which in my situation is 30 seconds.